# Link Multiple values in Single Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good Day

I have a table with all my data. In Column **Products** there are values linked to an index table but instead of it having a single value it has multiple values i.e. 900;190;170. If it was a single value I would have just use a **Left Join** between my two tables on Column **Products**. Is there a way to link it against the multiple values? 900 = Other, 190 = Books and 170 = Pens. The other problem is that it can be any amount of values in the **Product** column.

Thanks
Ruan

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: You should correct your database design first - are you able to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's a data set I am pulling from the client through an integration and they save it that way in their database.

Comment: use STRING_SPLIT to split the column into multiple rows and then go from there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Let me give that a try. Might be exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: `and they save it that way in their database` Is that the database you are working on ? If so, then why can you not correct the design ? You should really press on this, keep a design that is flaw will only get you more and deeper into trouble

Comment: The problem is when I get it it's already in that structure. I am now trying to fix the design on my side so I can report on it better. The client will not change their design unfortunately.

Comment: STRING_SPLIT would have worked 100%. Problem is that we are using SQL Server 2008 at this stage.

Comment: You can check stackoverflow for string splitting functions, i'm sure there are plenty :) Btw, this is why it's not bad to attach your sql server version as tag / in the question

Comment: Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Answer (score 0):

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(20)  NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE productsIndex (  
  indexName varchar(120)  NOT NULL,
  itemIndex varchar(20)  NOT NULL
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO products VALUES (900, 'Books');
INSERT INTO products VALUES (800, 'Other');
INSERT INTO products VALUES (190, 'Pen');

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO productsIndex VALUES ('900;190;170', 'test');
INSERT INTO productsIndex VALUES ('800;100', 'test2');

SELECT p.* ,pi.itemIndex
    FROM products p
    join productsIndex pi
        on p.id  in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(pi.indexName, ';'))
```

Comment: The OP mentioned in a comment that he is using sql server 2008, which unfortunate does not yet have the string_split function